# batch - echo multiple do in for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, windows-scripting

I'm unable to output 2 values on the same line using for /r.
The for loop is:

```
FOR /R C:\users\<user_name>\desktop\<folder_path> %%F in (*.*) do (
echo %%~nF >> C:\users\usernameA\desktop\test-forr.txt, #Output 1
C:\folderB\tail -n 1 C:\users\usernameA\desktop\folderABC\%%~nF.txt >> C:\users\joseph.borg\desktop\test-forr.txt # Output 2
```

The issue is that this loop prints the outputs ontop of each other. Can I place them in the same line next to each other (on the same line seperated by a comma) ?

The variable %%~nf stores text file names (without extension) in the same directory. The line C:\folderB\tail -n 1 refers to the linux command tail, which allows you to retrieve a number of 'n' lines starting from the bottom of the file specified (in this case the file specified is C:\users\usernameA\desktop\folderABC\%%~nF.txt).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R C:\users\<user_name>\desktop\<folder_path> %%F in (*.*) do (
 for /f %%a in ('C:\folderB\tail -n 1 C:\users\usernameA\desktop\folderABC\%%~nF.txt') do set "line=%%a"
 echo %%~nF,!line!>> C:\users\joseph.borg\desktop\test-forr.txt
)
```

I haven't tried this as I don't have `tail` but it should append `filename,lastlineofthefile` to the given output file (whose name appear to be different for the two separate redirections in your question.)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you @Magoo

Answer (score -1):

If you direct a command output with '>' or '>>' to a file, it will always be terminated with end of line character. Therefore you would have to create a variable which combines two outputs, then echo the variable into the file. However, your second output is generated by a command, so there is no way to store it in a variable. This is the limitation of windows batch. In conclusion, you current problem is non-solvable using only batch script.

Comment: Can you recommend how i can achieve this differently ? 
My target is: I have multiple text files in a folder. I need to create a new text file containing the name of every text file followed by the last line in that same text file.

Comment: Well, you can write a program to do this. Here's one in C:

Comment: Sorry but I don't see it.

Comment: `#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ofstream fout(argv[argc-1]);
    for(int i=1; i<argc-1; ++i) fout<<argv[i];
    fout.close();
}`
Compile it and name it say echoex. Usage:
echoex [any number of parameters or character strings] outputfile.
This extended ECHO command will put your parameters into the output file without EOL character.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know yet how to edit the code part properly.